# Change the default output form in mathematica 12

Tags: output-formatting, customization

Is there a simple way I can change the default output form in Mathematica 12? In Mathematica 11, this option was simply in the "preference", but I can't find it anywhere in Mathematica 12.

Comment: With `Preferences | Advanced | Open Option Inspector | Global Preferences` search using `Output` then change `New Cell Defaults | CommonDefaultFormatTypes | "Output"`

Comment: Thanks!! Got it!!